# C# Webforms - cannot send values set by jquery to server

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I am getting screen resolution of the client using jquery and setting label text. and in page load of back end c# code i am trying to access that. but as page load is executed first, I am not able to get the data set to label. I tried calling another c# function on some button click but on button click as it is runat server, according to my knowledge the page is reloaded and values are reset again so i am not getting values.
c# code is below where i am accessing width and height this did not work in pageload and button click function.

```
  string front = "width:" + width.Text + ";height:" + height.Text + 
  ";background - color: gray";
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#<%= width.ClientID %>").text(screen.width);
     $("#<%= height.ClientID %>").text(screen.height);
 });
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Label ID="width" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="height" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Note: On load the values are set and displayed on screen

Comment: Labels text won't be posted in your form / available server side (runat=server button click).  You can put the values in a hidden field `<input type='hidden' id='width' runat='server'/>` or you can make a jquery $.ajax call to a webservice in your application (cleaner, but possibly more complicated if you've not done this before).